# Should I use a rake task or migration to migrate data from a column to it's own table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, migration, rake

I have a `Books` table with an `author_name` column that is a string.
I have an `Author` table that I would like to populate based on the `author_name`.

The relationship is Authors have many Books, Book belongs to Author.
Books table has an `author_id` for the one to many relationship.

Other than that rake task can be run more than once, what are the benefits of writing this as a:

- migration
- rake task
- rails console

**Migration:**

```
class MoveAuthorDataToAuthors < ActiveRecord::Migration

  def up
    Book.all.each do |book|
      first_name, last_name = book.author_name.split(' ')
      Author.find_or_create_by(first_name: first_name, last_name: last_name).books << book
    end
  end

  def down
    raise ActiveRecord::IrreversibleMigration
  end

end
```

**Rake**

As a rake task it might look like

```
namespace :update_author_tabledb do
  desc "Move Author Data To Authors"
    Book.all.each do |book|
      first_name, last_name = book.author_name.split(' ')
      Author.find_or_create_by(first_name: first_name, last_name: last_name).books << book
    end
  end
end
```

**Console**

In my rails console I could do:

```
 Book.all.each do |book|
     first_name, last_name = book.author_name.split(' ')
     Author.find_or_create_by(first_name: first_name, last_name: last_name).books << book
 end
```

Comment: I would use a rake task since its a oneshot operation and not a transformation of the database schema as such. You should use `Book.find_each` which loads the data in batches. `author_name.split(' ')` is also naive and will give the wrong results if there is more than one first or last name (Brett Easton Ellis for example or F. Scott Fitzgerald).

Comment: A rake task can also be tested seperatly which is a huge bonus.

Comment: I suggest rake task.

Comment: @max please respond as with an answer and I will mark correct.  I agree with the reasoning to use a rake task since 1.  its a oneshot operation and 2.  not a transformation of the database schema which a migration should be